# Sharepoint Document Library with Item Content-Type?

Tags: custom-form, list-form, infopath, document-library, list

Here is my problem:

I wanted to use InfoPath forms, but due to complexity I have to switch to aspx forms. With Infopath Forms I could use a Forms Library, where the user is presented with `<Formname>` he can click on and a nice form opens - so far so good.

I know I can have custom aspx list edit/new forms, so I could pretty much design an aspx form for a list behaving just like infoPath (the user clicking on `<formname>` and a nice form opens).

The problem is that next to these "forms" or meta-data information, I also need to store Word documents in the library. No problem with a forms library: Create a document set for my form and put the form inside as well as the corresponding word document => Instant organization.

What is a way to handle metadata (a form) + documents? I can't have all form data attached to the word document as metadata, as the form itself is the leading document. Hence the title of this question: If I could put an "Item" content type within the document library, I could click on that item and attach a custom edit/new aspx form to the content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moontear, why not consider using [document sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559339.aspx)?

From what I understand of your requirements you want to do the following:
- Create a new item, with metadata attached.
- Add associated documents to that item

This seems perfectly aligned with [Document Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559339.aspx) functionality.

Comment: Yes, I am going with document sets right now with custom New, View and Edit forms - I just didn't put that into the question to see some other ideas which I might have missed.

Answer (score 1):

The key constraint of a document library over a list, is that a document library needs to have a document. I don't believe there is any way around that.

What you could do is: with your custom NewForm page, when someone saves, create a document library item using a fake document that will be the same in all items, but with a unique name. It could be anything, an image, word doc, or xml representation of the meta data. (this is what would be happening when using the InfoPath form)

Comment: The dummy document idea is interesting (and ugly at the same time).